# Mongoose product category design?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to create an eCommerce type of database where I have products and categories for the products using Mongodb and Mongoose. I am thinking of having two collections, one for products and one for categories. After digging online, I think the category should be as such:

```
var categorySchema = {
  _id: { type: String },
  parent: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'Category'
  },
  ancestors: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'Category'
  }]
};
```

I would like to be able to find all the products by category. For example "find all phones." However, the categories may be renamed, updated, etc. What is the best way to implement the product collection? In SQL, a product would contain a foreign key to a category.

A code sample of inserting and finding a document would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Why not keep it simple and do something like the following?

```
var product_Schema = {
  phones:[{
           price:Number,
           Name:String,
         }],
      TV:[{
           price:Number,
           Name:String
         }]
};
```

Then using projections you could easily return the products for a given key.  For example:

```
db.collection.find({},{TV:1,_id:0},function(err,data){
    if (!err) {console.log(data)}
})
```

Of course the correct schema design will be dependent on how you plan on querying/inserting/updating data, but with mongo keeping things simple usually pays off.

Comment: Two reasons: first there is a hierarchy for category documents. Second products have complex structure and may change categories.

Comment: That all sounds like relevant information in determining schema design.  Perhaps you can update the question with more information and an example of all the fields stored at the category level and all fields stored at the product level.  Also, I would mention how often you plan on changing category names, vs how often you plan on querying to get a list of products belonging to a category.  Can a product belong to multiple categories?  Without more information any response would be highly generalized.